# Как заставить парсер на Anglesharp работать постоянно?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

```
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Dom;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;




class parserWorker
{
    public async Task AllPhones (string url)
    {
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
        using var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
        using var doc = await context.OpenAsync(url);

        var name = doc.QuerySelector("h3");
        name = doc.GetElementsByClassName("title-root-zZCwT iva-item-title-py3i_ title-listRedesign-_rejR title-root_maxHeight-X6PsH text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL text-bold-SinUO")[0];
        var price = doc.QuerySelector("span");
        price = doc.GetElementsByClassName("price-text-_YGDY text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL")[0];
        var description = doc.QuerySelector("div");
        description = doc.GetElementsByClassName("iva-item-text-Ge6dR iva-item-description-FDgK4 text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL")[0];

        Console.WriteLine(name.TextContent + " " + price.TextContent);
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(description.TextContent);
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        string url = "https://www.avito.ru/moskva/telefony/mobilnye_telefony/apple-ASgBAgICAkS0wA3OqzmwwQ2I_Dc?cd=1";
        parserWorker phone = new parserWorker();
        while(true)
        {
            phone.AllPhones(url);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }

};
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы программа постоянно парсила страницу авито, и выдавала информацию о первом объявлении на странице (название, цену и описание). Делать это она должна до того момента, пока ее не закроют. Спустя некоторое время,программа должна будет удалить информацию о первом объявлении из консоли, и выдать о новом последнем. Максимум что мне удалось: программа выдает один раз последнее объявление, удаляет информацию, и больше ничего не происходит.

Comment: `await phone.AllPhones(url);` и `async Task Main()`

Answer (score 0):

Авито каждый запрос меняет хвосты у классов, блок объявления тебе нужно хватать другим способом

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]